# imacros SET !LOOP 53 (not 1 not 2) + scheduled tast

Tags: loops, automation, scheduled-tasks, imacros

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now.

I have a script that fills in fields on a webpage. I am using imacros chrome/firefox. The following does not work on either of them:

```
SET !DATASOURCE xyz.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 40
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !LOOP 53
URL
TAG
TAG
```

`!LOOP` does not start at row 53 of xyz.csv 
but starts from row 2.

Also, I will need to schedule this task to run every 30 minutes, but I am not sure how to do this.

The OS is Windows 7 64x, in case that matters.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the Datasource and Loop,

```
SET !DATASOURCE xyz.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 40
SET !LOOP 53
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL
```

For scheduling the script, refer the below URL's it might help..
http://wiki.imacros.net/Browser_Automation#Schedule_Tasks
https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job